# pandas dataframe fast apply function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe df with multiple columns (not sure how many). One of the columns is called `x`. I have defined a function `my_function` that takes 2 columns as inputs and does something them and returns a new column. 
I want to perform the `my_function(df[x], df[y])` on all columns of the dataframe (where `y` is all columns one by one except for `x`) and return a new df with exact same column names but update values from `my_function`:

```
new_df = my_function(df[x], df[y])
```

where y = all columns in df except for x. What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: For the *fastest* way, you need to tell us more about `my_function`. Your calculation may be vectorisable.

Answer (score 2):

if your function performs row-wise preprocessing, you can use the method apply (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) ) for each column:

```
columns = [item for item in df.columns.values if item!=x]
for c in coulmns:
   df[c] = df.apply(lambda row: my_function(row[c], row[x]) ,axis=1)
```

If not, can you share "my_function"'s body ?

Bests,

Answer (score 1):

You could try with something like this:

```
x = 'col_name'
[my_function(df[x], df[col]) for col in df if col!=x]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[1,2],'b':[4,3],'c':[5,9], 'd':[2,9]})
x = 'a'
df1 = pd.DataFrame({})
def my_function(a,b, name):
    c = a+b
    df1[name] = c

[my_function(df[x], df[col], name) for name, col in enumerate(df) if col!=x]
print df1
```

Output:

```
   1   2   3
0  5   6   3
1  5  11  11
```

Comment: Thanks! but is it possible to assign the result to a new_df with the same columns? (each col of df data is processed at my_function and the result of the process will be in new_df) ? I tried the following but doesn't work!                                               
 [new_df[col]= my_function(df[x], df[col]) for col in df if col!=x]

Comment: @sst I've updated the answer with an example, let me know if it is ok. I've added a 3rd parameter which is the columns name, but you can define the name inside the function if you prefer

Answer (score 1):

A quick and good solution for faster pandas apply function could be the use of swifter, here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import swifter

def fnc(m,x,c):
    return m*x+c

df = pd.DataFrame({"m": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "c": [1,1,1,1,1,1], "x":[5,3,6,2,6,1]})
df["y"] = df.swifter.apply(lambda x: fnc(x.m, x.x, x.c), axis=1)
```